# Wrong TimeZone Calculation in macOS bash?

Tags: macos, shell, date, timezone

When I do the following in macOS bash it returns the wrong Time Zone Information

- Input macOS
  `TZ="Asia/Yakutsk" date -j -f "%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S%z" "2014:09:28 14:46:56+1000" +"%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S%z"`
- Output macOS
  `2014:09:28 14:46:56+0900`

Conversely in bash on Debian Linux

- Input Linux `TZ="Asia/Yakutsk" date  --date "2014-09-28 14:46:56+1000" +"%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S%z"`
- Output Linux `2014:09:28 14:46:56+1000`

Anybody else experienced such timezone conversion bugs (+0900 versus +1000)? IMHO back in 2014 the timezone setting for Russia was still UTC+10 (according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakutsk_Time)

Thanks for thoughts / hints,
J

PS: After @KamilCuk 's hint,

Output on Linux

```
Asia/Yakutsk  Fri Dec 13 20:45:52 1901 UT = Sat Dec 14 05:24:50 1901 LMT isdst=0 gmtoff=31138
Asia/Yakutsk  Sat Dec 14 20:45:52 1901 UT = Sun Dec 15 05:24:50 1901 LMT isdst=0 gmtoff=31138
Asia/Yakutsk  Sat Mar 27 16:59:59 2010 UT = Sun Mar 28 01:59:59 2010 +09 isdst=0 gmtoff=32400
Asia/Yakutsk  Sat Mar 27 17:00:00 2010 UT = Sun Mar 28 03:00:00 2010 +10 isdst=1 gmtoff=36000
Asia/Yakutsk  Sat Oct 30 16:59:59 2010 UT = Sun Oct 31 02:59:59 2010 +10 isdst=1 gmtoff=36000
Asia/Yakutsk  Sat Oct 30 17:00:00 2010 UT = Sun Oct 31 02:00:00 2010 +09 isdst=0 gmtoff=32400
Asia/Yakutsk  Sat Mar 26 16:59:59 2011 UT = Sun Mar 27 01:59:59 2011 +09 isdst=0 gmtoff=32400
Asia/Yakutsk  Sat Mar 26 17:00:00 2011 UT = Sun Mar 27 03:00:00 2011 +10 isdst=0 gmtoff=36000
Asia/Yakutsk  Sat Oct 25 15:59:59 2014 UT = Sun Oct 26 01:59:59 2014 +10 isdst=0 gmtoff=36000
Asia/Yakutsk  Sat Oct 25 16:00:00 2014 UT = Sun Oct 26 01:00:00 2014 +09 isdst=0 gmtoff=32400
Asia/Yakutsk  Mon Jan 18 03:14:07 2038 UT = Mon Jan 18 12:14:07 2038 +09 isdst=0 gmtoff=32400
Asia/Yakutsk  Tue Jan 19 03:14:07 2038 UT = Tue Jan 19 12:14:07 2038 +09 isdst=0 gmtoff=32400
```

Output on macOS

```
.
.
Asia/Yakutsk  Sat Oct 30 17:00:00 1999 UTC = Sun Oct 31 02:00:00 1999 +09 isdst=0
Asia/Yakutsk  Sat Mar 25 16:59:59 2000 UTC = Sun Mar 26 01:59:59 2000 +09 isdst=0
Asia/Yakutsk  Sat Mar 25 17:00:00 2000 UTC = Sun Mar 26 03:00:00 2000 +10 isdst=1
Asia/Yakutsk  Sat Oct 28 16:59:59 2000 UTC = Sun Oct 29 02:59:59 2000 +10 isdst=1
Asia/Yakutsk  Sat Oct 28 17:00:00 2000 UTC = Sun Oct 29 02:00:00 2000 +09 isdst=0
.
.
Asia/Yakutsk  Sat Mar 24 16:59:59 2007 UTC = Sun Mar 25 01:59:59 2007 +09 isdst=0
Asia/Yakutsk  Sat Mar 24 17:00:00 2007 UTC = Sun Mar 25 03:00:00 2007 +10 isdst=1
Asia/Yakutsk  Sat Oct 27 16:59:59 2007 UTC = Sun Oct 28 02:59:59 2007 +10 isdst=1
Asia/Yakutsk  Sat Oct 27 17:00:00 2007 UTC = Sun Oct 28 02:00:00 2007 +09 isdst=0
Asia/Yakutsk  Sat Mar 29 16:59:59 2008 UTC = Sun Mar 30 01:59:59 2008 +09 isdst=0
Asia/Yakutsk  Sat Mar 29 17:00:00 2008 UTC = Sun Mar 30 03:00:00 2008 +10 isdst=1
Asia/Yakutsk  Sat Oct 25 16:59:59 2008 UTC = Sun Oct 26 02:59:59 2008 +10 isdst=1
Asia/Yakutsk  Sat Oct 25 17:00:00 2008 UTC = Sun Oct 26 02:00:00 2008 +09 isdst=0
Asia/Yakutsk  Sat Mar 28 16:59:59 2009 UTC = Sun Mar 29 01:59:59 2009 +09 isdst=0
Asia/Yakutsk  Sat Mar 28 17:00:00 2009 UTC = Sun Mar 29 03:00:00 2009 +10 isdst=1
Asia/Yakutsk  Sat Oct 24 16:59:59 2009 UTC = Sun Oct 25 02:59:59 2009 +10 isdst=1
Asia/Yakutsk  Sat Oct 24 17:00:00 2009 UTC = Sun Oct 25 02:00:00 2009 +09 isdst=0
Asia/Yakutsk  Mon Jan 18 03:14:07 2038 UTC = Mon Jan 18 12:14:07 2038 +09 isdst=0
Asia/Yakutsk  Tue Jan 19 03:14:07 2038 UTC = Tue Jan 19 12:14:07 2038 +09 isdst=0
```

Comment: Please post the output of `zdump -v -c 2010,2020 Asia/Yakutsk` on both systems (I have no idea if macos has zdump). It's odd that you pass `+10:00` vs `+1000` and `%Y:%m:%d` vs `%Y-%m-%d `? why change it?

Comment: Well, you see: `Asia/Yakutsk  Sat Oct 24 17:00:00 2009 UTC = Sun Oct 25 02:00:00 2009 +09 isdst=0 Asia/Yakutsk  Mon Jan 18 03:14:07 2038 UTC = Mon Jan 18 12:14:07 2038 +09 isdst=0` - the tz data differ, there is no +10 on 2014. I guess it's just outdated. || Please add 4 leading spaces to format block of text or select text and click the `{}`. Research how to format code in markdown.

Comment: Hi @KamilCuk, Thank you for your hint regarding zdump. I added the output to my edited post, and corrected the formatting! Thanks for your inputs - total newb on stackoverflow...
OK, now I know at least it wasn't my code!

Comment: Hi.  In the future, please pay attention to [what is on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  This question would have been better asked on another StackExchange site like [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Output on macOS
>
> ```
> Asia/Yakutsk  Sat Oct 24 17:00:00 2009 UTC = Sun Oct 25 02:00:00 2009 +09 isdst=0
> Asia/Yakutsk  Mon Jan 18 03:14:07 2038 UTC = Mon Jan 18 12:14:07 2038 +09 isdst=0
> ```

Your macos timezone information is outdated or invalid. Possible cause is that your system is outdated and you should update your `tzdata` package.

A 5 min search on google shows me multiple links on how to manually update tzdata database on MacOS. If a route of some "system update" is not available, then manually compile and install tzdata for `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Yakutsk`.

Comment: Yes, quite out of date.  This change was made in tzdata 2014f, released 2014-08-05.  The system would have had to not have been updated since before then.